# Will iOS always send memory warning before a memory crash?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, performance

Does iOS always send a memory warning before a memory crash or could it be the case that the app can sometimes terminate without a memory warning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be some cases where application will be terminated without memory warning.

Memory warning is delivered on main thread. Your application will not receive memory warning if its main thread is blocked. Also from [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html)

> If your app’s main thread is blocked at launch time, the system could
>   kill the app before it even finishes launching. If the main thread is
>   blocked at quitting time, the system could similarly kill the app
>   before it has a chance to write out crucial user data

Also, if the memory of OS increases quickly, it may not get time to send memory warning to the application and it will be terminated without warning.

Comment: that's true. nice explanation. i faced the condition in which my application was taking a long time to launch ( due to some heavy tasks in the main thread) and after waiting a few seconds system simply kills the app.